# Project Euler problem 10, wrong answer but why (Java)

Tags: java

newbie question I know, but I can't figure out what the error is in my code for this question. The problem asks to get the sum of all prime numbers below 2,000,000.

I can't figure out why my code works for smaller sets, yet when I wait patiently for my code to finish for 2,000,000 it spits out a wrong answer. 1,179,908,154 in this case.

**DISCLAIMER** I realize the code I've written is extraordinarily inefficient/wasteful and that I should use the Sieve of Eratosthenes among other things. I'm just trying to figure out why it gives the wrong answer.

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        
        int[] primes = new int[2000000];
        int index=0;
        int ans=0;
        
        //finding primes and populating array
        for (int candidate=2; candidate<=2000000; candidate++) {
            System.out.println(candidate); //so I can watch the numbers go up
            for (int divisor=1; divisor<=candidate; divisor++) {
                
                if (candidate%divisor==0 && candidate==divisor) {
                    primes[index]=candidate;
                    index++;
                    break;
                }
                
                if (candidate%divisor==0 && candidate!=divisor && divisor!=1) {
                    break;
                }               
                
            }
        }
        
        //adding primes
        for (int m=0; m<primes.length; m++) {
            ans+=primes[m];
        }
        
        System.out.println(ans);
    }
```

Comment: Do you know what the max value of an int is?  Do you know what happens when you exceed this amount?

Comment: ...Oh my god I'm an idiot. Can't believe I missed that. ty

Comment: Happens to everyone. Remember `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem lies within the type of `ans`.

In Java, ints are 4 bytes long, which means they can only store numbers ranging from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.
The sum of all prime numbers below two million is far greater than these values.
What's happening here is that your `int` variable overflows and "goes around" (it "skips" from the maximum value to the minimum value).

Try changing the type of `ans` to long.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same wrong result with my Java program loaded into my local Scala REPL.

```
scala> org.oeis.primes.PrimeLister.listPrimes(2_000_000)
res3: java.util.ArrayList[Integer] = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, ...

scala> import collection.JavaConverters._
import collection.JavaConverters._

scala> res3.asScala
       ^
       warning: object JavaConverters in package collection is deprecated (since 2.13.0): 
Use `scala.jdk.CollectionConverters` instead
res4: scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[Integer] = Buffer(2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, ...

scala> res4.toList
res5: List[Integer] = List(2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, ...

scala> res5.scanLeft(0)(_ + _)
res7: List[Int] = List(0, 2, 5, 10, 17, 28, 41, 58, 77, 100, 129, 160, 197, ...

scala> res5.scanLeft(0L)(_ + _)
res12: List[Long] = List(0, 2, 5, 10, 17, 28, 41, 58, 77, 100, 129, 160, 197, ...

scala> res7.takeRight(1)
res15: List[Int] = List(1179908154)

scala> res12.takeRight(1)
res16: List[Long] = List(142913828922)
```

So yeah, try using `long` to add up the primes.